# Any webdav or ftp server source code for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to implement a webdav or ftp server in iOS. Can someone suggest a webdav or ftp server open source project?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean a webdav/ftp client? A server is something else entirely.

Answer (score 3):

How about [TouchHTTPD](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchHTTPD)?

[TouchHTTPD / Projects / iPhone WebDAV Server](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchHTTPD/tree/master/Projects/iPhone%20WebDAV%20Server)

```
TouchWebDAV Caveats

BASIC Auth Only (Digest auth coming soon)
No SSL
Not optimised for caching headers (If-*)
Cannot use Finder WebDAV and TouchWebDAV server on same machine!
WebDAV locking is totally fake.
Set attribute operations unsupported (so chmod, touch will not work)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#webdav-server-in-ios-apps it seems to be good and active.